# What is the complexity of numpy's irr function?

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity, finance, irr

Given an array of length n, assuming there is a solution for the internal rate of return, what is the complexity of the numpy irr() function? [irr() source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/financial.py#L601-L678)

I had a look at the code but wasn't able to calculate it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm seems to have complexity O(n^3), since it's computing the eigenvalues of the companion matrix of your input. None of the other computations in the function have nearly as long of a time complexity.